# Windows Phone 8.1 Admob failed to recieve ads on device, but works on emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm trying to add Admob banner on my Windows Phone 8.1 app, I've done everything same with Google's documentation and When I run it on emulator, it works perfectly. I see test ads and normal ads on screen, but when I run it on real device (Lumia 920) it fails and OnFailedToReceivedAd works and gives me NoFill as errorcode. I'm searching over 2 days on internet. Please help me. **My codes below from MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
 AdView bannerAd = new AdView
        {
            Format = AdFormats.Banner,
            AdUnitID = "ca-app-pub-4629040566186464/6355149637"
        };
        bannerAd.ReceivedAd += OnAdReceived;
        bannerAd.FailedToReceiveAd += OnFailedToReceiveAd;
        DrawingSurfaceBackground.Children.Add(bannerAd);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
     //   adRequest.ForceTesting = true;
        bannerAd.LoadAd(adRequest);


    }
    private void OnAdReceived(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Received ad succesfully");
        txtas.Text = "Received ad succesfully";
    }
    private void OnFailedToReceiveAd(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs errorCode)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Received ad unsuccesfull"+errorCode.ErrorCode);
        txtas.Text = "Received ad unsuccesfull";
    }**
```

I made this app on Unity3d, Because of Google Admob SDK doesn't support Windows Phone, so I've done steps on this website http://gamedevtodied.blogspot.com.tr/2015/06/unity3d-how-to-integrate-admob-for.html. As I said it works on emulator but not working on device.

Comment: Do you see the test ads on your lumia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the `NoFill` error many times on many of your users devices. This is because not much people on the `Windows Phone` platform advertise using `Google AdMob`, and because they did not create an SDK for `Windows Phone 8.1` which use 90% of all Windows Phone devices.

The `NoFill` error is normal, and will occur much less when you release your app. You can register on a different ad provider, for example `Microsoft PubCenter` or `AdDuplex` and when the `NoFill` error occurs, simply display another ad provider ads as a fallback.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if you feel this is a good enough answer.

Answer (score 0):

AdDuplex can't permit to monetize, only promote the app. For a developer is unthinkable not have revenues. It work for free? And eat air... Microsoft pubcenter not work, million of case still wait a response from Microsoft. The reality is that Google stopped to develop SDK of AdMob and actual version is not compatible with Windows Phone 8.1, this is a bad and illegal politic.